# How could I debug in nodejs, any tool similar to pdb or pry in Ruby or Python

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran my script by

> node debug sample.js

It stopped at the target position.

Somehow, I don't know how to inspect the variables.

For example, I want to print out the variable `db` ,  but it couldn't.

Any recommend debugger tool on `node.js`

Thanks

## sample.js

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.2
(function() {
  var MongoClient, print;
  print = require('awesome-print');
  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    debugger;
    db.command({
      listCollections: 1
    }, function(err, o) {
      debugger;
      return print(o["cursor"]);
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

## exception

```
 20
 21 });
debug> print(db)
repl:1
print(db)
^
ReferenceError: print is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:975:21)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
debug> db
repl:1
db
^
ReferenceError: db is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:975:21)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

**2022 update**

You can use `node inspect`

badloop.js:

```
let orders = [341, 454, 198, 264, 307];

let totalOrders = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= orders.length; i++) {
  debugger; //Breakpoint
  totalOrders += orders[I];
}
```

console.log(totalOrders);

`node inspect badloop.js`

`c` or `cont`: Continue execution to the next breakpoint or to the end of the program.

`n` or `next`: Move to the next line of code.

`s` or `step`: Step into a function

`o`: Step out of a function

you can use the `help` command inside de debugger to see all available commands.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the "repl" command in the command-line debugger. Also [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) is a great way to hook up chrome's awesome devtools to a node process. You can learn how to use node-inspector in my [blog post: Lighting up your javascript with the debugger](https://peterlyons.com/js-debug/)

Comment: Ok, I just wrote my script and run it as simply standalone script. I haven't thought that I need to debug on webbrowser. its kind of more complicated than I thought. thank you :)

Comment: The command line debugger is fine, too. Did you try typing `repl` when it pauses at your breakpoint then `console.log(db)`? Inspecting variables isn't available in the top-level command set, you need to `repl` first.

Comment: @LukAron fixed.

Comment: Yes indeed we need to get into `repl`. I really miss the `pdb` way of doing it where you can both print variables and run debugger commands without switching in and out repl

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [CodeLite IDE](http://codelite.org) (a free, cross platform, open source IDE). Since version 8.1 we fully support [debugging Node.js applications](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Nodejs#toc6)